# PhalconPHP: Include table in relationship

Tags: php, orm, phalcon, relationships

Let's say I have three tables, like so:

```
people
------
id
name


credits
-------
id
person_id
event_id
position


events
-----
id
name
year
```

In the people model (as well as the events model), I have a one to many defined pointing to the credits.  In the credits I have a belongsTo pointing to people, and one pointing to events.

I have a $person object that I get by:

```
$person = People::findFirst();
```

Now, I know that I can get access to events simply by:

```
$person->events;
// or:
$person->getEvents();
```

... but...  how can I do this *AND* get access to the associated credit data as well?  Is there a built in/Phalcon way, or do I just have to go through $person->credits?

Thanks!

EDIT:

In other words, is there a way to "include" associated data in the query?  I know that, under the hood, it's doing a JOIN on credits.  I'd love for that call to also include the credits in the SELECT statement.  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Judging by increased head-hurting model questions you are not having much of a fun time :P

Comment: Heh, well, just trying to figure out how to make it work, but be as performant as possible.